# WebStorm unable to recognise Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webstorm

I'm having an issue with an existing project in React Next.js, previously it was working fine but now it's unable to recognise the project and files.
Hence I cannot search for files, and also cannot find in files.

I have tried `File > Invalidate Caches` but it's still not able to recognise.

Does anyone know what causes this issue, and how to fix it?

Screenshots attached.

WebStorm Project not recognised:

[image: WebStorm Project not recognised]

WebStorm Project files not recognised:

[image: WebStorm Project files not recognised]

WebStorm cannot search files:

[image: WebStorm cannot search files]

WebStorm cannot find in files:

[image: WebStorm cannot find in files]

Comment: Try to close WebStorm, backup and delete _.idea_ directory in the project root.

Comment: Your project config seems to be somehow corrupted -- based on your screenshot WebStorm treats all files as "outside of the project". Delete `.idea` folder as per comment above and re-open the project (may need to use "Open" and point to the project root folder) -- the IDE will create a new project from existing files.

Comment: Thank you! Tried and it works, project files are detected again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary based on [@s0xzwasd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13576700/s0xzwasd) and [@LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) suggestion:

**Issue:**

Project config is somehow corrupted. Files are treated as "outside of the project".

**Fix/Solution steps:**

1. Close the project from WebStorm.
2. Backup and delete `.idea` directory in the project root.
3. Re-open project.
4. IDE will create a new project from existing files / treating the files as included in the project.